# Function with an $x$ not in simple form

Tags: functions, terminology

I've stumbled upon a practice example in an old textbook which I find confusing. Maybe it's because I haven't reached part of an explanation yet (went through pages, haven't found anything of help). Also, task doesn't have a solution offered. Some do, some don't - it's a weird textbook of ye old age (and country).

Here's what it states (sorry for possible rough translation):

For a given function:

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-6x+9}-\sqrt{x^2+6x+9}$$

a) How much is $f(x)$, for $-2 < x < 2$?

b) Calculate $f(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})$

I admit I haven't seen this before, so I would really appreciate if someone would guide me through this, step by step preferable since I have no one to ask. I struggle with the meaning here of how much is $-2 < x < 2$. I understand this can't be an $x$ value itself. I guess it's supposed to be a range of a given function? So what is it then? A range of values I should put into a function or something?

What I did is I have "simplified" the function first (don't know if there's a term for it?). 
here's what I did so far:

1: $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-6x+9}-\sqrt{x^2+6x+9}$

2: $f(x)=\sqrt{{(x-3)}^2}-\sqrt{{(x+3)}^2}$ <- factored quadratics basically

3: $f(x)=\lvert(x-3)\rvert-\lvert(x+3)\rvert$ <- cancelled out sqrts with ^2 exponents

but how would I proceed now with given tasks?

PS
Sorry I couldn't think of a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise in carefully working through the meaning of the square root symbol and keeping track of sign changes.  You've done an excellent job of removing the square roots to obtain the expression

$$f(x)=|x-3|-|x+3|$$

The only thing you have to do now keep track of sign changes in the absolute value expressions.  For example, $|x-3|=x-3$ when $x\ge3$ and $|x-3|=3-x$ when $x\le3$.  Likewise, $|x+3|=x+3$ when $x\ge-3$ and $|x+3|=-(x+3)$ when $x\le-3$.  Since part a) is only asking about the interval $-2\lt x\lt2$, we have

$$f(x)=3-x-(x+3)\quad\text{for }x\in(-2,2)$$

and this simplifies to

$$f(x)=-2x$$

Part b) should now be very easy, once you notice that $x=\sqrt2-\sqrt3$ falls in the interval $-2\lt x\lt2$.

In point of fact, the sign changes at $x=3$ and $-3$ mean that

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
6\quad&\text{for }x\le-3\\
-2x\quad&\text{for }-3\lt x\lt 3\\
-6\quad&\text{for }3\le x
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you expand a bit on how you've arrived to this expression here: $f(x)=3-x-(x+3)\quad\text{for }x\in(-2,2)$ ? You've said that |x-3| = x-3 when x is larger or equal to 3, but here we have 2... or I'm probably comprehending this wrong.

Comment: @MathAgain, if $x$ is less than $2$, then $x$ is automatically less than $3$, hence $|x-3|=3-x$.  It's all a matter of reasoning with inequality signs.  Don't despair; I have a hard time keeping these things straight myself.  (So maybe I'm the one who should despair....)

Comment: thanks again! I went through it back and forth like a busy squirrel and now finally got it. Keeping track of all things going on takes a lot of concentration I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

It's badly worded, but I believe the first question is asking you to find $f((-2,2))$ (in case you aren't familiar with the notation, that's the range of $f$ where its domain is taken to be the interval from $-2$ to $2$). For the second, substituting it in should be fine.

Comment: It confused me to a point I am not sure anymore. Initial thought was exactly that - numbers between -2 and 2, but not including those. Thanks! I'll leave it open for some time though. Maybe someone has some new insight and it isn't badly worded.

Comment: Oops, you're right there - it is indeed looking for the image of the open interval $(-2,2)$, not the closed interval as I originally said. Fixed it now.